# Using async/await with util.promisify(fs.readFile)?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to learn async/await and your feedback would help a lot.

I'm simply using fs.readFile() as a specific example of functions that has not been modernized with Promises and async/await.

(I'm aware of fs.readFileSync() but I want to learn the concepts.)

Is the pattern below an ok pattern? Are there any issues with it?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

//promisify converts fs.readFile to a Promised version
const readFilePr = util.promisify(fs.readFile); //returns a Promise which can then be used in async await

async function getFileAsync(filename) {
    try {
        const contents = await readFilePr(filename, 'utf-8'); //put the resolved results of readFilePr into contents
        console.log('✔️ ', filename, 'is successfully read: ', contents);
    }
    catch (err){ //if readFilePr returns errors, we catch it here
        console.error('⛔ We could not read', filename)
        console.error('⛔ This is the error: ', err); 
    }
}

getFileAsync('abc.txt');
```

Comment: That looks good to me!

Answer (score 4):

import from fs/promises instead, like this:

```
const { readFile } = require('fs/promises')
```

This version returns the promise you are wanting to use and then you don't need to wrap readFile in a promise manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more ways on using async/await

EDITED: as [@jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) pointed in comments, of course you have to use standard NodeJS features with built in methods like `fs.readFile`. So I changed `fs` method in the code below to something custom, where you can define your own promise.

```js
// Create your async function manually
const asyncFn = data => {
  // Instead of result, return promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Here we have two methods: resolve and reject.
    // To end promise with success, use resolve
    // or reject in opposite
    //
    // Here we do some task that can take time.
    // For example purpose we will emulate it with
    // setTimeout delay of 3 sec.
    setTimeout(() => {
      // After some processing time we done
      // and can resolve promise
      resolve(`Task completed! Result is ${data * data}`);
    }, 3000);
  });
}

// Create function from which we will
// call our asyncFn in chain way
const myFunct = () => {
  console.log(`myFunct: started...`);
  // We will call rf with chain methods
  asyncFn(2)
  // chain error handler
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
  // chain result handler
  .then(data => console.log(`myFunct: log from chain call: ${data}`));
  // Chain call will continue execution
  // here without pause
  console.log(`myFunct: Continue process while chain task still working.`);
}

// Create ASYNC function to use it
// with await
const myFunct2 = async () => {
  console.log(`myFunct2: started...`);
  // Read file and wait for result
  const data = await asyncFn(3);
  // Use your result inline after promise resolved
  console.log(`myFunct2: log from async call: ${data}`);
  console.log(`myFunct2: continue process after async task completed.`);
}

// Run myFunct
myFunct();
myFunct2();
```

Comment: There's really no reason to make your own promise version of `fs.readFile()` or really any other `fs` function as promisified versions already exist in that module such as `fs.promises.readFile()`.  And, if you're going to make your own promisified version, you can use `util.promisify()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Really? Wow... ) And what about educational purpose? fs.readFile() here is just legacy from example above, question was basically about async/await logic in general... "I'm trying to learn async/await..." - Phu Ngo said in the beginning of his question.

Comment: If you're going to teach them how to use promises with `fs.readFile()` you should teach them where the already promisified version is that is ready to use.  And, if you're promisifying something that has the standard nodejs asynchronous callback signature then, you should be teaching them to use `util.promisify()`.  I get teaching, but teach them the way they should be doing it.  I didn't downvote you (someone else apparently did that) - I'm just suggesting ways your answer could be improved.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok, thanks for comment. I've modified my answer to make it more about custom promises.